# What type of Typescript return value should I use for a $http call that returns nothing other than success?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I created a service using Typescript:

```
class ConfigService implements IConfigService {

    public admin = {};
    public adminBackup = {};
    public user = {};
    public loaded = false;

    constructor(
        private $http: ng.IHttpService,
        private $q: ng.IQService
        ) {

    }

    static $inject = [
        '$http',
        '$q'
    ];

    put = ():ng.IHttpPromise<> => {
        var defer = this.$q.defer();
        if (angular.equals(this.admin, this.adminBackup)) {
            return defer.resolve();
        } else {
            this.$http({
                data: {
                    adminJSON: JSON.stringify(this.admin),
                    userJSON: JSON.stringify(this.user)
                },
                url: '/api/Config/Put',
                method: "PUT"
            })
                .success(function (data) {
                    this.adminBackup = angular.copy(this.admin);
                    this.userBackup = angular.copy(this.user)
                    return defer.resolve();
                });
        }
        return defer.promise;
    };

}
```

I also created this interface:

```
interface IConfigService {
     put(): ng.IHttpPromise<>;
}
```

However the code is giving me an error saying:

```
Error   3   Cannot convert 'void' to 'ng.IHttpPromise<any>'.    

Error   4   Cannot convert 'ng.IPromise<{}>' to 'ng.IHttpPromise<any>':
    Type 'ng.IPromise<{}>' is missing property 'success' from type 'ng.IHttpPromise<any>'.
```

Comment: When you create your own defered object its promise is of type `ng.IPromise`, basically if you are using vs and as a suggestion when you hover over a particular method it will tell you what type it returns and you can derive the return type from that. There is nothing wrong in doing `return defer.resolve();` because the return is not evaluated anyways in your case since you are returning a deferred promise of your own and resolving/rejecting it by yourself, but it is very often used when you want to short circuit your conditional statements.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use

```
ng.IPromise<void>
```

Also you could let it implicitly type it for you if you don't declare a return type and don't use that interface.

Also there should be no return statement here :

```
return defer.resolve();
```

Just :

```
defer.resolve();
```

Comment: Thank you. One thing I had to do to make it work is to change the <void> to <any>. It was giving a message saying the promise returned {}. Is what I did an okay thing to do?

Comment: @Alan, use this: var deferred = $q.defer<void>(); 
This will let you return void.

Answer (score 3):

When I ran into this issue I found that I wasn't able to use `ng.IPromise<void>` as the declarations for `ng.IHttpPromise<>` demanded that I return an object.

For example:

```
public saveTechnicianNote = (jobNumber: string, technicianNote: Model.TechnicianNote): ng.IPromise<void> => {
    var data = {
        jobNumber: jobNumber,
        subject: technicianNote.subject,
        details: technicianNote.details
    };
    return this.$http.post(this.urlFactory.saveTechnicianNote, data);
}
```

threw up an error that `Type IHttpPromise<{}> is not assignable to IPromise<void>`.

To get around this I made it return `ng.IPromise<any>`. Not 100% ideal but it was the best solution I could come up with that didn't require me to extend on `angular.d.ts`

Final Code:

```
public saveTechnicianNote = (jobNumber: string, technicianNote: Model.TechnicianNote): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    var data = {
        jobNumber: jobNumber,
        subject: technicianNote.subject,
        details: technicianNote.details
    };
    return this.$http.post(this.urlFactory.saveTechnicianNote, data);
}
```